# blazor interface not updating correctly when removing item from List<>

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a child component that is being generated inside a foreach loop for List<> of models.  That child component has a delete button on it and when clicked, it sends a message to the parent and the model for that component is removed.  The interface should update with that component no longer being visible on the view.  The interface is updating and removing a child component from the view, but unless it's the last item in the list, it's not removing the correct one (but only on the view).  If I click another button on the page, the interface updates correctly with the removed view gone.  I have added a call to StateHasChanged() right after the item is removed from the list.  I have also put a breakpoint in the method that is removing the item.  The model being passed in is correct and when inspecting the list after the item is removed, it is also correct.

Is there some other way I can force the interface to update after I remove this item from the list?  As I said above, when I click another button or perform any other action on the page, the children components update correctly.  I have tried using System.Reactive in an observable to pass the message to the parent from the child as well as Invoking an EventCallback from the child to pass the message to the parent, same behavior with both.

here is the relevant code on the parent:

```
    _removeDogSubscription = DogCommunicationService.RemoveDogAgent.Subscribe(dog =>
    {
        DeleteDog(dog);         
    });

private void DeleteDog(DogModel dog)
{
    Dogs.Remove(dog);
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: Can you give more context around `RemoveDogAgent`. What data type is it, how is it called?

Comment: @key is usually the cause...

Comment: @key is probably the solution...  But we have no markup code to go by.

Comment: @BrianParker you were right.  I hadn't even heard of key but after googling it based on your comment, that fixed my issue.  Is that something I should use for every list I loop over in blazor?

Comment: Yes when you are re-ordering lists such as in a delete.  It providers the Renderer with an "id" key for the row.

Answer (score 0):

It's full explained at [Invoke component methods externally to update state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/synchronization-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#invoke-component-methods-externally-to-update-state)

> In the event a component must be updated based on an external event, such as a timer or other notification, use the `InvokeAsync` method, which dispatches code execution to Blazor's synchronization context. For example, consider the following notifier service that can notify any listening component about updated state. /.../

To fix the issue, just change `StateHasChanged();` by `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);`

Comment: In this case the trigger is _"... child component has a delete button"_.  So InvokeAsync is not required here.

Comment: In code, you can see that action is triggered by an event. Quoting docs _In the event a component must be updated based on an external event, such as a timer or other notification, use the InvokeAsync method, which dispatches code execution to Blazor's synchronization context._

Comment: It's never wrong to wrap it in an InvokeAsync() but when the event is triggered by a button it's not an 'external event' as meant in the docs. The OP solved it another way.